# Importing JSON-like data into Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file that is similar to JSON data but isn't formatted fully that I would like to parse into Pandas in Python. I could cycle through and manipulate the data until it's what I need it to be, but I wanted to see if there was a better solution than what I can think of.

Sample file:

```
{"fruit": "Apple", "Quantity": "5"},
{"fruit": "Orange", "Quantity": "10"},
```

Comment: Read line by line and read as JSON dict?

Answer (score 1):

first remove end comma.use sed to replace comma and write to another file

```sh
sed -r 's/\S*,\S*$//g' json_file > data.jl
```

```py
#use lines True to read json line file.
df = pd.read_json("data.jl",lines=True)
```